Does @attached macros work in the preview body?
I have write MockBuilder macro which generates a single mock instance. Here is a DeveloperCardViewParameters which has MockBuilder macro and generation mock property.
@MockBuilder()
struct DeveloperCardViewParameters {
    let icon: Image
    let title: String
    let description: String
    #if DEBUG
    static var mock: DeveloperCardViewParameters {
        .init(
            icon: MockBuilderSupportedType.generate(elementType: .image, generatorType: .random) as! Image,
            title: MockBuilderSupportedType.generate(elementType: .string(), generatorType: .random) as! String,
            description: MockBuilderSupportedType.generate(elementType: .string(), generatorType: .random) as! String
            )
       }
    #endif
 }

here is DeveloperCardView Preview
 #if DEBUG
    #Preview(body: {
        DeveloperCardView(parameters: DeveloperCardViewParameters.mock) // This line I get error -> "Type 'DeveloperCardViewParameters' has no member 'mock'"
    })
 #endif

Does @attached macros work in the preview body?

Try to show a preview that way works fine. here is a explanation why #preview doesn't work
#if DEBUG
struct DeveloperCardView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DeveloperCardView(parameters: DeveloperCardViewParameters.mock)
    }
}
#endif


#Preview is also a macro, so its arguments cannot see names generated by other macros.
Excerpt from SE-0389,

Second, if the output of one macro expansion (say, @myMacro1(x)) introduces a name (say, y) that is then used in the argument to another macro expansion (say, @myMacro2(y)), then the order in which the macros are expanded can affect the semantics of the resulting program. It is not generally possible to introduce an ordering on macro expansions, nor would it be desirable, because Swift generally tries not to have order dependencies among declarations in a program. Incidental orderings based on the names introduced by the macro don't help, either, because names of declaration macros can be specified as arbitrary and therefore cannot be predicated.
[...]
To address these issues, a name introduced by a macro expansion is not visible within macro arguments for macros the same scope as the macro expansion or any of its enclosing scopes.

So this behaviour is intentional.
To work around this, you can declare a protocol that declares a mock:
protocol HasMock {
    static var mock: Self { get }
}

@MockBuilder()
struct DeveloperCardViewParameters: HasMock {
    ...
}

Now, typechecking the #Preview closure works, because the compiler can see that DeveloperCardViewParameters conforms to HasMock, so it must have a mock.
Note that the : HasMock conformance clause must not be added by a macro, otherwise we run into the same problem again.
